# write vector as linear combination of null and column space vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that the nullspace N(A) and row space of a matrix are orthogonal to each other and am trying to write a vector x as a linear combination of the two.

My matrix A:

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

The rank of A = 3 and thus the Null space dimension = 1.  I have found the null space basis Z =

$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

If given a point $x_1$ = $(1 \ 3 \ 1 \ 2)^{\top}$, how do I write $x = p_i + q_i $ where $p \in N(A) \ \And \ q \in R(A^{\top})$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know how to compute the projection of one vector onto another vector?

Comment: The null space is orthogonal to the row space, **not the column space**. In this example the column space is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ while the null space is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$. Perhaps you wanted to say that the null space of a matrix and the column space of its transpose are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $a\pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1}+b\pmatrix{1\\-1\\-1\\1}+c\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\1}+d\pmatrix{-1\\-1\\1\\1}=\pmatrix{1\\3\\1\\2};$ i.e.,

$$a+b-d=1\tag1$$

$$a-b+c-d=3\tag2$$

$$a-b+d=1\tag3$$ and

$$a+b+c+d=2.\tag4$$

You could solve these equations by adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ to solve for $a$ and $b-d$, subtracting $(2)$ from $(4)$ to solve for $b+d$ (hence solving for $b$ and $d$), and then using $(2)$ or $(4)$ to solve for $c$.

Comment: Yes I realize now that there are 4 equations and 4 unknowns so an exact solution for p and q exist by simply creating the matrix as per above taking its inverse and multiplying it to x.